# Mysql wherein match all

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a typical m:m relationship between users and groups through a joining table. Each user can be part of multiple groups.

```
users
-------
id
name

groups
-------
id
name

user_groups
------------
id
user_id
group_id
```

I would like try find all users that are in multiple groups. For example, all users that are in groups 3, 4, 5. Note that the users must belong to ALL of these groups.

At first I tried the following, but of course this is not correct since this returns `OR` results instead of `AND`

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_groups ug on u.id = ug.user_id
where ug.group_id in (3, 4, 5)
```

I also tried having a separate join for each group_id that I am searching for (which works), but is not efficient.

How can this be best achieved

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT
    u.id, u.name
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN user_groups ug on u.id = ug.user_id
WHERE ug.group_id in (3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
HAVING COUNT(u.id) = 3
```

The `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT` force the query to find users that are in all 3 groups.

**EDIT:** If you do not want to use `GROUP BY` an ugly way to do it would be to use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT
    u.id, u.name
FROM users u
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_groups ug 
            WHERE u.id = ug.user_id AND ug.group_id = 3)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_groups ug 
            WHERE u.id = ug.user_id AND ug.group_id = 4)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_groups ug 
            WHERE u.id = ug.user_id AND ug.group_id = 5)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Whilst it works for 1 relationship, I actually have a few joining tables that need to be added to the query. So, its not only groups (and user_groups as the join), but also plans (and user_plans) and statuses (and user_statuses), for example.

Comment: @JonoB This answer was directed towards the question posted, to join other tables you may have to to use this as a sub query and then JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to get all info about users:

```
select *
  from users u
  join (
       select user_id
         from user_groups
        where group_id in (3, 4, 5)
        group by user_id
       having count(*) > 1
       ) ugr on u.id = ugr.user_id
```

If you want to have the output like: `user_id, user_name, count(*)` then:

```
select u.id as user_id, u.user_name, count(*)
  from user_groups ugr
     , users u
 where u.id = ugr.user_id
   and ugr.group_id in (3, 4, 5)
 group by u.id, u.username
 having count(*) > 1
```

Adjust `where group_id in (3, 4, 5)` according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work, it should return all the common `user_id`.

```
select user_id 
  from user_groups
 where user_id in (
         select user_id 
           from user_groups
          where group_id = 3
            and user_id in (
                  select user_id
                    from user_groups
                   where group_id = 2
                     and user_id in (
                           select user_id 
                             from groups 
                            where group_id = 1
                         )
               )
      )
```